# Best way to prevent parameter tampering and send values with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I am posting a form to the controller and making it asynchronous. I am storing values in input form hidden. When a button is clicked, a javascript function is called. It both fetches the value from an input field, as well as a value from input form hidden. It then sends a json string to the controller to handle this request.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize] 
public ActionResult DoSomeStuff (string leagueName, string doSomething)  {
    var service = new Service(_db);
    var league = service.GetLeague(leagueName);
    if (league != null) {
        // validate doSomething
        league.Action = doSomething;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return new EmptyResult(); 
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitForm", function () {
    var json = {
            "leagueName": $("input[name=leagueName]").val(),
            "doSomething": $("input[name=doSomething]").val()
    };

    $.post("/Home/DoSomeStuff/", json, function () {
        // async display something
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="doSomething">
<button type="submit" id="submitForm"</button>
<input type="hidden" name="leagueName" value="@item.League.LeagueName" />
```

> What is the best way to let javascript fetch a stored value (more secure way then input type hidden)?
>
> How can I prevent some user from altering the value from the input type
>   hidden field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I prevent some user from altering the value from the input
>   type hidden field?

You cannot!

> What is the best way to let javascript fetch a stored value (more
>   secure way then input type hidden)?

The general rule is, do not trust data coming from client. You should always validate it on server before doing anything.

If you are worried about a user update the league name field value in the form  to some other users league name and post it, What you should be doing is, explicitly checking whether the user has proper permission to do something on the posted league in your server code.

```
[HttpPost, Authorize] 
public ActionResult DoSomeStuff (string leagueName, string doSomething)  {
    var service = new Service(_db);
    var league = service.GetLeague(leagueName);

    // Now check whether the current user has access/permission 
    // to perform some operation on this league.
    // Ex : if(!service.IsUserAuthorizedToDoSomething(league))
    //     {
    //      return View("NotAuthorized");
    //     }
    //to do: Return something
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What if I validate that this user has permission to both leagues. Is it then no way to see if the league name was altered?

Comment: If the user has access to both leagues. he can update/perform any actions. Another thing you can do is to keep the unique `Id` of League also in a hidden field in the form. And use use that to validate/get the league from db.  Since the user has access to this league also, he can alter the id if he wants. There is nothing much you can do. If you absolutely want to prevent this, generate a random string in GET action and set that in your form in hidden field, and validate it on HttpPost. Since this is per request-session. Your second user wont know this secret string. This is a dirty way though

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

If the value needs to come from the client (and be part of the HTTP request) then there's absolutely nothing you could do to prevent the client from modifying its contents. If the client is not supposed to modify the contents of some fields then those fields have nothing to do in your markup and be part of the postback HTTP requests (be it as hidden fields or whatever markup element comes to your mind). They should safely reside on your server (database?) and be retrieved using some identifier coming from the client. Obviously whether the client can access the information related to this identifier is subject to something called authorization. Basically you should first know who your client is (authentication) and then verify in your data model if this client has access to the corresponding records. It's as simple as that.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize] 
public ActionResult DoSomeStuff (string id, string doSomething)  
{
    var service = new Service(_db);
    var league = service.GetLeagueById(id);
    if (!HasAccessToLeague(User.Identity.Name, league)) 
    {
        // you are not suppose to modify the contents of this league
        // throw him a 404 or something
    }
    else
    {
        if (league != null) 
        {
            // validate doSomething
            league.Action = doSomething;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return new EmptyResult(); 
}
```

obviously the implementation of the `HasAccessToLeague(string username, string leagueId)` method will greatly depend on your data model and how your authorization logic.

Also you used `XSS` in your question title but here your problem is not about `XSS` or javascript but rather designing authorization layer in your web application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What if I validate that this user has permission to both leagues. Is it then no way to see if the league name was altered?

Comment: If the user is allowed to modify the league name then don't make the league name as a hidden input, but rather a normal textbox where the user will be able to modify its name. But use the unique identifier of the league as id when querying. And if the user has access to both leagues then why care if he has modified the name? If you need to much to detect this case then you could make your UPDATE statement include the league name coming from the user in the WHERE statement in addition to the `id`. In this case if 0 rows are affected you will know that the user changed the name.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

of course its possible to do this! After all, your server app manages to track who the currently logged on user is using insecure client storage.

When a user logs on, the server will generate a secret message and store it in an encrypted token that's passed to the client and bak in a cookie (which is just another piece of unsecured client data storage). When you send requests to the server, it gets the cookie, decrypts it, and checks the data inside to tell who the user is.

You can do the same - for the hidden fields, encrypt them, put them in a hidden input (or a cookie if you prefer) and send them back to the server. However, you can only use them in your client javascript if you send them plain text as well, which means you need to still perform some checking on the server, but that checking can be as simple as comparing the encrypted values with the hidden form values, if any do not match, reject the request.

things to bear in mind though, encrypion is slow. It can be quicker to fetch the values from a DB instead, though you might use a cache for these. YMMV.

An alternative option is to generate a javascript file with the values in and ensure that the client browser cannot edit them using security features such as content-security-policy. The disadvantage is an inability to use these values in html (as obviously the user can edit them there) so you'll have to pass data back to the server via js calls.